# How to implement log changes in a storm project locally using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, logback, apache-storm

I can't figure out how to implement changes to a local storm project using Eclipse. I can implement changes no problem on server deployed code by modifying the `./logback/clusters.xml` file (e.g. changing log level from `INFO` to `ERROR`).
How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly. What do you mean by "local storm project"? Do you execute using LocalCluster? In this case, you need to create a file "logback.xml" and put you logger configuration there. logback.xml must be in your classpath, ie, you can put it into "src" folder to enable Eclipse to find it. Or you put it somewhere else and extend your classpath accordingly.