# Disable LocalCluster Logging in Apache Storm

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-storm

I'm trying to get started with Apache storm by running the [example code](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/storm/starter). I'm working with storm 0.10.1-beta1 off of a maven repository.

Unfortunately, when I run these, the console is flooded with info level logs, drowning out any `System.out.print()` calls that I've added. Is it possible to change the log level when running off of a LocalCluster? I've tried the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206821/how-to-disable-turn-off-the-logging-feature-from-storm) and none of the solutions seem to be working.

From the link, Changing the `Config.TOPOLOGY_DEBUG` property to false doesn't remove the info level logs, and using the code from the link, I can't even use `logger.setLevel((Level) Level.FATAL)` as I get "The method setLevel(Level) is undefined for the type Logger" despite it clearly being listed in the log4j api.

**Edit 1**:
I also tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923617/how-to-implement-log-changes-in-a-storm-project-locally-using-eclipse/) and I put an xml called `logback.xml` into ./src with the following config:

```
<configuration monitorInterval="60">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
     <PatternLayout pattern="%-4r [%t] %-5p %c{1.} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="WARN"/>
    <Root level="WARN">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

Still no luck though. Is there any additional config required to tell storm to use the custom log settings?

**Update:** It turns out that storm 0.10.x switched to using log4j2 instead of logback, so adding a log4j2.xml with the configuration above finally worked!

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923617/how-to-implement-log-changes-in-a-storm-project-locally-using-eclipse/

Comment: Just tried that and no luck (see edit).

Comment: I tried you method but not work, I put the log4j2.xml both in src and src/main/resources/ still not work.

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration works for me:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: So it turns out that storm 0.10.x [switched to log4j2](https://storm.apache.org/2015/06/15/storm0100-beta-released.html) which is why the logback.xml file wasn't working. Making a log4j2.xml in ./src did work, however. I tested your configuration with storm 0.9.1-incubating and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good to know for future reference :)

Comment: I tried keeping a `log4j2.xml` with the above content in my program's src folder, but the `INFO` and `DEBUG` logs of the local cluster continued being displayed. For a newbie like me, could you please provide more details on where the file should be kept and how `Storm` would recognize the presence of the `log4j2.xml` file in a `Netbeans` project folder? I'm using `Gradle` to get the `Storm` jar.

Comment: I am not familiar with Netbeans... In Eclipse, the file is located in `src/resources`. But I am sure, an Internet search will reveal the answer for Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

To make it clear for newbies:
When running on local cluster: Whether you use `log4j` or `slf4j` for your own application's logging, you will eventually have to use a `log4j2.xml` or a `logback.xml` file [where you set](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/logback-xml-example/) the configuration of how you want logging to happen.

It is in this file; your own application's log4j or logback xml file, that you have to paste the configuration which tells your application not to show the logs.

So simply add this anywhere between the `<configuration>` and `</configuration>` tags.

```
 <logger name="org.apache.storm" level="OFF"/>
 <logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="OFF"/>
```

Comment: In `log4j2.xml`, this part should not be "anywhere"; it should be in the `<Loggers>`.

Answer (score 1):

To define a system property `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml` is a keypoint on Storm 1.0.0

The `log4j2.xml` could be a fake or non-existing file.

Comment: No.. Storm just searches the `log4j2.xml` file under classpath. If it is a maven project, you can put it under `src/main/resources`, which works because I am using it like this. It is Maven convention to include `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` directly under classpath. In Eclipse you may have to configure classpath (remove `src` and add these two folders).